# Strange assignment, TextView to Bundle, after decompiling, why?

Tags: java, android, decompiling

I created a simple application, a counter app, that upon pressing a button increments a integer by one and updates a textview. The code can be seen below:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    public static int count = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.count);
        textView.setText(Integer.toString(count));
        final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                count++;
                textView.setText(Integer.toString(count));
            }
        });
    }
    ...
}
```

After decompiling the same app with dex2jar and jd-gui i received the following code back:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    public static int count = 0;

    protected void onCreate(final Bundle paramBundle) {
        super.onCreate(paramBundle);
        setContentView(2130903040);
        paramBundle = (TextView)findViewById(2131296257);
        paramBundle.setText(Integer.toString(count));
        ((Button)findViewById(2131296256)).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View paramAnonymousView) {
                MainActivity.count += 1;
                paramBundle.setText(Integer.toString(MainActivity.count));
            }
        });
    }
    ...
}
```

On the following line:

```
        paramBundle = (TextView)findViewById(2131296257);
        paramBundle.setText(Integer.toString(count));
```

How is it possible for the system to set the textview to the paramBundle? And why is this happening? paramBundle is of type Bundle and TextView is not a subclass of Bundle, further more Bundle is final according to the decompiled version. Did something go wrong upon decompiling? Is the information from the decompiler wrong or why do we get this result?

---

Edit:

```
# virtual methods
.method protected onCreate(Landroid/os/Bundle;)V
    .locals 3
    .param p1, "savedInstanceState"    # Landroid/os/Bundle;

    .prologue
    .line 17
    invoke-super {p0, p1}, Landroid/app/Activity;->onCreate(Landroid/os/Bundle;)V

    .line 18
    const/high16 v2, 0x7f030000

    invoke-virtual {p0, v2}, Lcom/example/rawa/helloworld/MainActivity;->setContentView(I)V

    .line 20
    const v2, 0x7f090001

    invoke-virtual {p0, v2}, Lcom/example/rawa/helloworld/MainActivity;->findViewById(I)Landroid/view/View;

    move-result-object v1

    check-cast v1, Landroid/widget/TextView;

    .line 21
    .local v1, "textView":Landroid/widget/TextView;
    sget v2, Lcom/example/rawa/helloworld/MainActivity;->count:I

    invoke-static {v2}, Ljava/lang/Integer;->toString(I)Ljava/lang/String;

    move-result-object v2

    invoke-virtual {v1, v2}, Landroid/widget/TextView;->setText(Ljava/lang/CharSequence;)V

    .line 22
    const/high16 v2, 0x7f090000

    invoke-virtual {p0, v2}, Lcom/example/rawa/helloworld/MainActivity;->findViewById(I)Landroid/view/View;

    move-result-object v0

    check-cast v0, Landroid/widget/Button;

    .line 23
    .local v0, "button":Landroid/widget/Button;
    new-instance v2, Lcom/example/rawa/helloworld/MainActivity$1;

    invoke-direct {v2, p0, v1}, Lcom/example/rawa/helloworld/MainActivity$1;-><init>(Lcom/example/rawa/helloworld/MainActivity;Landroid/widget/TextView;)V

    invoke-virtual {v0, v2}, Landroid/widget/Button;->setOnClickListener(Landroid/view/View$OnClickListener;)V

    .line 30
    return-void
.end method
```

I'm definitely no smali expert, only a novice. But i decoded the application using apktool as well and received the smali code above. From my understanding, the savedinstance (paramBundle) is loaded in to p1(=v3) and used in onCreate, and it is not used in any way in line 20 or 21. To me this point towards a decompling error? Keep in mind that apktool allows for building the application again and thus no data may be lost when decompiling.

Comment: I like this question

Comment: @ElJazouli Glad you found it interesting, please up vote the question so it get more attention.

Comment: can you post a link to your APK i'll try and decompile it and see if it's a decompile issue or whatever, because it's really strange

Comment: I'd vote for inaccurate decompilation as I agree with you on that it doesn't make much sense. Personally I treat decompilaton with jd-gui as a best effort endeavour. Out of curiosity: what happens if you DO use the saveInstanceState in the code - e.g. a simple null check would suffice?

Comment: @ElJazouli you can find the apk here:
http://upload.davidgoransson.se/app-release.apk

Comment: @ZsomborErdődy-Nagy Did as you said, after setContentView I checked if paramBundle was null and if that was the case, use Log.d and print a string. Result is exactly the same with exception of the added if statement.

Comment: Hah, that's even more weird.

Comment: so it's confirmed that it's not a decompile issue, here's a suggestion following what @ZsomborErdődy-Nagy said, add this at the end of `onCreate` : `savedInstanceState.keySet()` and see what the result is

Comment: @ElJazouli usage of savedInstanceState.key() resulted in a change in the usage of paramBundle, now it received it's own variable called localTextView. I also updated the question with the samli code generated from apktool.

Comment: looks like a bug on decompile.. Nice question would like to know the answer aswell

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cause is that the type of local variables has changed, but some decompilers fail to handle it correctly.

Here's your `onCreate` code decompiled with dex2jar + [javap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javap.html):

```
  protected void onCreate(android.os.Bundle);
    Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: aload_1
       2: invokespecial #20                 // Method android/app/Activity.onCreate:(Landroid/os/Bundle;)V
       5: aload_0
       6: ldc           #21                 // int 2130903040
       8: invokevirtual #25                 // Method setContentView:(I)V
      11: aload_0
      12: ldc           #26                 // int 2131230720
      14: invokevirtual #30                 // Method findViewById:(I)Landroid/view/View;
      17: checkcast     #32                 // class android/widget/TextView
      20: astore_1
      21: aload_1
      22: getstatic     #12                 // Field count:I
      25: invokestatic  #38                 // Method java/lang/Integer.toString:(I)Ljava/lang/String;
      28: invokevirtual #42                 // Method android/widget/TextView.setText:(Ljava/lang/CharSequence;)V
      31: aload_0
      32: ldc           #43                 // int 2131230721
      34: invokevirtual #30                 // Method findViewById:(I)Landroid/view/View;
      37: checkcast     #45                 // class android/widget/Button
      40: new           #6                  // class com/example/test/MainActivity$1
      43: dup
      44: aload_0
      45: aload_1
      46: invokespecial #48                 // Method com/example/test/MainActivity$1."<init>":(Lcom/example/test/MainActivity;Landroid/widget/TextView;)V
      49: invokevirtual #52                 // Method android/widget/Button.setOnClickListener:(Landroid/view/View$OnClickListener;)V
      52: return
```

Here `aload_0` is local variable for MainActivity object, and `aload_1` is local variable for Bundle object. The source of the problem occured at code #20, when **it stores the reference of just-retrieved TextView object into local variable 1** (`astore_1`), which was previously storing the Bundle object!

This is done since the Bundle object is not used for the rest of the method, therefore it's more efficient to reuse its local variable instead of a new variable. However it also means that decompilers need to work extra hard to produce correct Java code.

Comment: Thanks for the in-depth explanation.

Comment: By the way, can we be sure that the cause of this is Java Decompiler? Or can the output provided from dex2jar the source of the error? Because Apktool does not reuse the same variable.

Comment: @Rawa I went back and check out the same class compiled by javac before it's been processed into dex. I found that javac does no optimization at all, so 4 variables are used instead of 2 in the decompiled version. Having said that, I think (not an expert) that Java bytecode locals variables is allowed to store data of different types, which may be why some decompilers reuses local variables while others don't. After all it's more work for the decompiler to figure out that some variables can be reused than to just blindly grab variables as they are needed, they wouldn't do it if it's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The smali-code you provided looks correct. Running the app also works with the original source code. However, the code provided by jd-gui *doesn't even compile*.

I got curious and decompiled your app with dex2jar. I uploaded the resulting MainActivity.class to [this website](http://www.javadecompilers.com/).

**The interesting part:** Some decompilers ([Procyon](https://bitbucket.org/mstrobel/procyon/wiki/Java%20Decompiler) and [Fernflower](https://github.com/fesh0r/fernflower)) generated the correct code and made separate variables for both the Bundle and the TextView. [JAD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JAD_(JAva_Decompiler)) and [CFR](http://www.benf.org/other/cfr/) however **made the same mistake as jd-gui.** They both used the Bundle-variable for the TextView.

---

It looks like you can blame jd-gui for the bug. Sadly, I can't tell you why it occurs.